# Use class algebra to prove that if $A⊆B$ and $C=B−A$, then $A=B−C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In A Book Of Set Theory by Charles C. Pinter, in Exercise 1.3 Question 11, that question is asked. I have solved it without class algebra.

[image: My solution]

However, using class algebra, I have gotten stuck at a certain step. I’ve tried introducing the union with the empty set and replacing it with A and it’s complement as well as the other letters, but all approaches I take seem to leave me with a lingering letter. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

[image: Stuck here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: if you have to show that $A = B - C$, I would also start with the more complex side ($B - C$), and see if I could rewrite that to the simpler side $A$.

Now, you know that $A \subseteq B$, which means $A \cap B = A$

Also, for any $X$ and $Y$: $X - Y = X \cap Y'$

So, since you know that $C = B - A$, you know that $C = B \cap A'$

So:

$B - C = B \cap C' = B \cap (B \cap A')' = B \cap (B' \cup A) = (B \cap B') \cup (B \cup A)  = \emptyset \cup (B \cap A) = B \cap A = A$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A \subseteq B$, then

$$B=A\cup(B\setminus A)=A\cup C$$

$$C=B\setminus A=B\cap A'$$

$$C'=(B\cap A')'=B'\cup A$$

$$B\cap C'=B\cap (B'\cup A)= (B\cap B')\cup (B\cap A)=\emptyset \cup A $$

$$B\cap C'=A $$

$$A= B\setminus C$$